# diablo 3 won't start after add optirun prefix

Tags: nvidia, wine, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I've been trying to run the Diablo3 in the ubuntu 13.10 for a while now, sadly without a success... My problem is, that i can't run it with optirun. If I just type

```
wine "/home/belo/.wine/drive_c/games/Diablo III/Diablo III.exe"
```

everything is fine, until I run the game, obviously, because it is running on the intel graphics... When I try to run

```
optirun wine "/home/belo/.wine/drive_c/games/Diablo III/Diablo III.exe"
```

the battle.net loading appears for a short time, but it disappears right away and nothing happens after. Do you have any suggestions please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried `primusrun`? I think this is the successor to `optirun`. Also, have you added the [Bumblebee PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/stable) and upgraded to the latest version?

Comment: yeah primusrun solved it. but if I run optirun bash and then diablo with wine, everything went OK. the only thing I need to add is setarch to 32bit

Comment: glad you got it working. If you can, please answer your question below, so that it might help others. Cheers.